# NamespaceHandler in spring

Tags: spring, xml-namespaces

What is a NamespaceHandler? What is the need to write our custom NamespaceHandler?

Please explain me the significance of NamespaceHandler. Provide me Any links on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It handles specific XML tags found inside a file, such as `<log:return />`, which is the `return` tag inside the `log` namespace.

The best reference is often the [Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html).

It is useful if you want to use your custom XML tags in an XML configuration:
http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364131/Authoring-Custom-Namespaces-in-Spring-20

If you have a framework and want to add Spring integration to your framework, it could be useful. In that case it would be more important to define the equivalent annotations.

Comment: how are you relating it to annotations?

Comment: Just because when you create a framework with custom XML namespaces, it would be nice to create also custom annotations, in my opinion.